# How I can generate different random numbers in one moment in c++?

Tags: c++, random, std

How I can generate different random numbers in one moment in c++?

Now I use

```
while ( flag )
{
   ....
   srand( time( NULL) ); 
   int rndSig = rand() % 10 + 1;
   ......
}
```

But at one moment all numbers are equal. How I can generate different numbers in while loop?

Comment: what do you mean by all equal. What you have would produce random numbers between [1-10].

Comment: @Gunner: no it won't. Using srand() just before rand() causes all number generated in a short duration to be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the srand outside of the while loop.  You only need to call it once, rand() keeps static state.

Answer (score 5):

You don't seed the random generator directly before you use it. Just use `srand` once before the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Like this :

```
srand( time( NULL) ); 
while ( flag )
{
   ....
   int rndSig = rand() % 10 + 1;
   ......
}
```

If you need different distribution, or better randomness, you need to use a library.